# How do i Maven fetch dependency version in shell script

Tags: maven

I have one project artifact version say

```
apple-0.0.1
```

In another project mango i have dependency to apple, which i have added in `pom`.
In mango there is one shell script.

Which needs to refer to

```
apple-{apple.version}
```

How can i dynamically populate this value in shell script by reading the `pom` during package time on mango project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the shell script into src/main/resources and let maven do it's filtering job.

Comment: Give the man a bone: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html